# Square Connect API: How does one handle partial authorizations? (prepaid debit/etc)

Tags: square, square-connect

There are several ways Square Connect could handle this, I need to know which they use:

1. If insufficient funds on the card, return that the entire payment failed. (normal, expected, as if they don't do split payments).
2. If insufficient funds on the card, return that the payment succeeded. May send fields indicating partial payment (amount left on card), seperate from success/fail. (Currently we'd send the order as if the full amount was approved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attempt to charge a pre-paid debit card that has less money on it than you attempt to charge, the transaction will return that the payment failed.